# Left float form and center align table

Tags: html, css, css-float, text-align

I have a form that floats to the left of the page. On the same line is a table that is supposed to be centered with the text-align style. Why is it that it is off-center? How do i get it to stay right in the middle?

Comment: Please post markup and ideally a JSFiddle so we can look at it.

Comment: @jdwire: float:left for the form and text-align:center for the table. Without the form, the table would align without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

text-align is to center text and images, if you need table to center add to the parent div: `margin:0px auto;`

for example:

```
table_wrap_div {width:200px; margin: 0px auto;}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. It also sends each table on to a line of their own, which I don't want. Currently, my tables are inline-blocks, but ive also tried block. In any case, why can't I use text-align for tables? Seems to work just fine for the other tables. It's just the one at the top that shares a line with the form that is an issue.